# Web Worker missing fetch response headers

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, fetch, web-worker

I'm using web workers to scrape response header cookies from a website in a chrome extension. When the request is executed on the main thread the response of the request is as expected, with the cookies from the request present. However, when executing the exact same request on a web worker script, the response headers are mostly missing. Below attached are the two responses

[Main Thread Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vctfR.png)

[Web Worker Response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v6a1w.png)

Answer (score 0):

It could be due to a bug that I have personally reported (but of which I haven't had any feedback yet).

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1178285&q=&can=4

**EDIT:**
If you are working on a manifest V2 extension AND you have a browser version less or equal to 88 you might give it a try...
Visit the chrome flags page, and enable the #same-site-by-default-cookies flag.
This is the direct link: [LINK](http://chrome://flags/#same-site-by-default-cookies)
If the extension works again in the web worker after enabling that flag it means the problem is due to the bug already reported.
Remember to disable that flag after this test.

Comment: Let's say browser version is above 88, there is no workaround for this until google comes around?

Comment: There could be. Track exactly what cookies are sent with its values when you are requesting the URL in main thread. Then do same thing when you request same resource throught web worker. Check differences between 2 requests, adapt cookies in web worker request creating missing cookies or modifying the existing ones with the "main thread" values, finally send the request again saying a prayer
You can work on cookies throught chorme.cookies API.
Try also to poke chromium  bug reporting staff telling your story...
Good luck